# What is the new method for "remove_twitter" in dfm (Quanteda)?

Tags: quanteda, dfm

I get the following message. Using R 3.6.3, RStudio 1.2.5042, and Quanteda 2.0.1.

```
corpus.dfm <- dfm(corpus, remove_twitter = TRUE)
'remove_twitter' is deprecated; for FALSE, use 'what = "word"' instead.
```

I understand what deprecated means in context, but I don't understand the second part: use 'what = "word"' instead. Could an experienced user clarify, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit the deprecation message is not the most helpful, but the idea is that we have changed the default tokenizer behaviour in v2.  `what = "word"` now preserves social media tags (@username and #hashtag) and there is no option to remove the `@` or `#` from the tags, with the `what = "word"` (the default).

To remove the tag symbols, you need to use `what = "word1"` (the pre v2 default) or now, use any other tokenizer that creates a list output, for instance the word tokenizer from the **tokenizers** package.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.1

txt <- "This is a @username and #hashtag."

# preserve social media tags (default)
tokens(txt, remove_punct = TRUE, what = "word")
## Tokens consisting of 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "This"      "is"        "a"         "@username" "and"       "#hashtag"

# remove social media tags (using tokenizers pkg)
tokenizers::tokenize_words(txt, lowercase = FALSE) %>%
  tokens()
## Tokens consisting of 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "This"     "is"       "a"        "username" "and"      "hashtag"

# remove social media tags (using quanteda)
tokens(txt,
  remove_twitter = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE,
  what = "word1"
)
## Warning: 'remove_twitter' is deprecated; for FALSE, use 'what = "word"' instead.
## Tokens consisting of 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "This"     "is"       "a"        "username" "and"      "hashtag"
```

**Update regarding quanteda >= v2**

This option has been removed in v2.  The `tokens` documentation now states:

> In versions < 2, the argument `remove_twitter` controlled whether social
> media tags were preserved or removed, even when `remove_punct = TRUE`.
> This argument is not longer functional in versions >= 2. If greater
> control over social media tags is desired, you should user an
> alternative tokenizer, including non-quanteda options.

So now, these symbols are always preserved by **quanteda**'s default tokeniser:

```r
> tokens("This is a #hashtag and @username.")
Tokens consisting of 1 document.
text1 :
[1] "This"      "is"        "a"         "#hashtag"  "and"       "@username" "."
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just a head's up. I'm using version 2.1.2, and now I have the following warning message (using what="word1"):

'remove_twitter' is defunct; see 'quanteda Tokenizers' in ?token

So, if you really need to remove social media tags, you should use the tokenizers package as Ken Benoit said.

This is a comment, not a answers, sorry If I don't have the reputation.